# Problems setting up and adding classes and compiling in UnrealEngine

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, support

I just installed UDK and Tried compiling a project in C++ at first it didn't compile I searched for it and it only said like "try again till it works" and I did then it worked "magically" with no explanation for what happened wrong but I said ok moved to adding a class and had a problem adding it it says "Successfully added but couldn't compile" and I recompile and it fails to do that so I searched and asked till someone told me to download and try the source code and I did but this is what I get after setting it up and generating the project trying to build it from the VS solution :

```
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1509/3074] MagicLeapARPinImplModule.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1510/3074] Module.MagicLeapAudio.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1511/3074] Module.AvfMediaEditor.gen.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1512/3074] Module.ImagePlateEditor.gen.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1513/3074] Module.CodeView.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1514/3074] Module.MagicLeapMediaEditor.gen.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1515/3074] Module.DatasmithIFCTranslator.gen.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1516/3074] Module.MagicLeapHandTracking.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1517/3074] Module.DatasmithDeltaGenTranslator.gen.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1518/3074] Module.ControlRigEditor.cpp
1>cl : Command line error D8049: cannot execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\c1xx.dll': command line is too long to fit in debug record
1>  [1519/3074] Module.MagicLeapEyeTracker.gen.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1520/3074] Module.MagicLeapAudio.gen.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1521/3074] Module.MagicLeapController.gen.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1522/3074] Module.MagicLeapController.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1523/3074] Module.MagicLeapEyeTracker.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1524/3074] Module.SteamVREditor.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
1>  [1525/3074] UE4Editor-AssetRegistry.dll
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1340: failed to create heap: error code = 8
1>  [1526/3074] UE4Editor-NetCore.dll
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1102: out of memory
1>  [1527/3074] UE4Editor-SourceCodeAccess.dll
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1102: out of memory
1>  [1528/3074] UE4Editor-AudioPlatformConfiguration.dll
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1102: out of memory
1>  [1529/3074] Module.QuadricMeshReduction.cpp
1>D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Containers/Map.h(115): fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space
1>  [1530/3074] UE4Editor-ClothingSystemEditorInterface.dll
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\ClothingSystemEditorInterface\UE4Editor-ClothingSystemEditorInterface.suppressed.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\ClothingSystemEditorInterface\UE4Editor-ClothingSystemEditorInterface.suppressed.exp
1>  [1531/3074] UE4Editor-GeometryAlgorithms.dll
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Experimental\GeometryProcessing\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\GeometryAlgorithms\UE4Editor-GeometryAlgorithms.suppressed.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Experimental\GeometryProcessing\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\GeometryAlgorithms\UE4Editor-GeometryAlgorithms.suppressed.exp
1>  [1532/3074] UE4Editor-PropertyPath.dll
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\PropertyPath\UE4Editor-PropertyPath.suppressed.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\PropertyPath\UE4Editor-PropertyPath.suppressed.exp
1>  [1533/3074] UE4Editor-DynamicMesh.dll
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Experimental\GeometryProcessing\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\DynamicMesh\UE4Editor-DynamicMesh.suppressed.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Experimental\GeometryProcessing\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\DynamicMesh\UE4Editor-DynamicMesh.suppressed.exp
1>  [1534/3074] UE4Editor-TextureFormatAndroid.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\TextureFormatAndroid\UE4Editor-TextureFormatAndroid.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\TextureFormatAndroid\UE4Editor-TextureFormatAndroid.exp
1>  [1535/3074] UE4Editor-SlackIntegrations.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\SlackIntegrations\UE4Editor-SlackIntegrations.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\SlackIntegrations\UE4Editor-SlackIntegrations.exp
1>  [1536/3074] UE4Editor-NetCore.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\NetCore\UE4Editor-NetCore.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\NetCore\UE4Editor-NetCore.exp
1>  [1537/3074] UE4Editor-PropertyPath.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\PropertyPath\UE4Editor-PropertyPath.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\PropertyPath\UE4Editor-PropertyPath.exp
1>  [1538/3074] UE4Editor-AssetRegistry.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\AssetRegistry\UE4Editor-AssetRegistry.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\AssetRegistry\UE4Editor-AssetRegistry.exp
1>  [1539/3074] UE4Editor-Concert.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Developer\Concert\ConcertMain\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\Concert\UE4Editor-Concert.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Developer\Concert\ConcertMain\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\Concert\UE4Editor-Concert.exp
1>  [1540/3074] UE4Editor-DynamicMesh.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Experimental\GeometryProcessing\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\DynamicMesh\UE4Editor-DynamicMesh.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Experimental\GeometryProcessing\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\DynamicMesh\UE4Editor-DynamicMesh.exp
1>  [1541/3074] UE4Editor-ClothingSystemEditorInterface.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\ClothingSystemEditorInterface\UE4Editor-ClothingSystemEditorInterface.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\ClothingSystemEditorInterface\UE4Editor-ClothingSystemEditorInterface.exp
1>  [1542/3074] UE4Editor-ReliabilityHandlerComponent.dll
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\ReliableHComp\UE4Editor-ReliabilityHandlerComponent.suppressed.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\ReliableHComp\UE4Editor-ReliabilityHandlerComponent.suppressed.exp
1>  [1543/3074] UE4Editor-GeometryAlgorithms.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Experimental\GeometryProcessing\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\GeometryAlgorithms\UE4Editor-GeometryAlgorithms.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Experimental\GeometryProcessing\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\GeometryAlgorithms\UE4Editor-GeometryAlgorithms.exp
1>  [1544/3074] ShaderCompileWorker-ImageWrapper.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\ShaderCompileWorker\Development\ImageWrapper\ShaderCompileWorker-ImageWrapper.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\ShaderCompileWorker\Development\ImageWrapper\ShaderCompileWorker-ImageWrapper.exp
1>  [1545/3074] UE4Editor-PacketHandler.dll
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\PacketHandler\UE4Editor-PacketHandler.suppressed.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\PacketHandler\UE4Editor-PacketHandler.suppressed.exp
1>  [1546/3074] UE4Editor-MeshConversion.dll
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Experimental\GeometryProcessing\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\MeshConversion\UE4Editor-MeshConversion.suppressed.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Experimental\GeometryProcessing\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\MeshConversion\UE4Editor-MeshConversion.suppressed.exp
1>  [1547/3074] UE4Editor-CollectionManager.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\CollectionManager\UE4Editor-CollectionManager.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\CollectionManager\UE4Editor-CollectionManager.exp
1>  [1548/3074] UE4Editor-GeometryCollectionCore.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\GeometryCollectionCore\UE4Editor-GeometryCollectionCore.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\GeometryCollectionCore\UE4Editor-GeometryCollectionCore.exp
1>  [1549/3074] UE4Editor-SlackIntegrations.dll
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\SlackIntegrations\UE4Editor-SlackIntegrations.suppressed.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\SlackIntegrations\UE4Editor-SlackIntegrations.suppressed.exp
1>  [1550/3074] UE4Editor-SourceCodeAccess.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\SourceCodeAccess\UE4Editor-SourceCodeAccess.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\SourceCodeAccess\UE4Editor-SourceCodeAccess.exp
1>  [1551/3074] UE4Editor-AudioPlatformConfiguration.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\AudioPlatformConfiguration\UE4Editor-AudioPlatformConfiguration.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\AudioPlatformConfiguration\UE4Editor-AudioPlatformConfiguration.exp
1>  [1552/3074] ShaderCompileWorker-TextureFormatPVR.dll
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\ShaderCompileWorker\Development\TextureFormatPVR\ShaderCompileWorker-TextureFormatPVR.suppressed.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\ShaderCompileWorker\Development\TextureFormatPVR\ShaderCompileWorker-TextureFormatPVR.suppressed.exp
1>  [1553/3074] UE4Editor-RiderSourceCodeAccess.dll
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Developer\RiderSourceCodeAccess\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\RiderSourceCodeAccess\UE4Editor-RiderSourceCodeAccess.suppressed.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Developer\RiderSourceCodeAccess\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\RiderSourceCodeAccess\UE4Editor-RiderSourceCodeAccess.suppressed.exp
1>  [1554/3074] UE4Editor-LauncherServices.dll
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\LauncherServices\UE4Editor-LauncherServices.suppressed.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\LauncherServices\UE4Editor-LauncherServices.suppressed.exp
1>  [1555/3074] UE4Editor-MeshSolverUtilities.dll
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Experimental\GeometryProcessing\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\MeshSolverUtilities\UE4Editor-MeshSolverUtilities.suppressed.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Plugins\Experimental\GeometryProcessing\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\MeshSolverUtilities\UE4Editor-MeshSolverUtilities.suppressed.exp
1>  [1556/3074] UE4Editor-TargetPlatform.dll
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\TargetPlatform\UE4Editor-TargetPlatform.suppressed.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\TargetPlatform\UE4Editor-TargetPlatform.suppressed.exp
1>  [1557/3074] Module.EditorSubsystem.gen.cpp
1>  [1558/3074] Module.NiagaraCore.cpp
1>  [1559/3074] Module.AudioMixerXAudio2.cpp
1>  [1560/3074] UE4Editor-AudioMixerXAudio2.lib
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\AudioMixerXAudio2\UE4Editor-AudioMixerXAudio2.lib and object D:\Unreal\UnrealEngine-release\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\AudioMixerXAudio2\UE4Editor-AudioMixerXAudio2.exp
1>  [1561/3074] Module.OpenGLDrv.3_of_3.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(44,5): error MSB3073: The command "..\..\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat -Target="UE4Editor Win64 Development" -Target="ShaderCompileWorker Win64 Development -Quiet" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6.
1>Done building project "UE4.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am having some errors that it skips I guess like

```
1>  [1515/3074] Module.DatasmithIFCTranslator.gen.cpp
1>c1xx : error C3859: Failed to create virtual memory for PCH
1>  c1xx: note: the system returned code 1455: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
1>
1>
1>  c1xx: note: please visit https://aka.ms/pch-help for more details
1>c1xx : fatal error C1076: compiler limit: internal heap limit reached
```

and I searched all that and one answer was to add "interface IUnknown;" in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\combaseapi.h before "extern "C++""

also verified my account on windows

but still having the same problem I guess

im working on a laptop: OS windows 10 64bit, intel core i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80 (1.99), RAM 8GB, GPU Radeon 520, intel UHD Graphics 620 memory 2048mb

and which is better the source code or the "Epic Launcher" installation way ?

I need someone to help me with both the Epic Launcher problem which is mintioned first then the source code if possible

help please ? what's wrong with this engine I used godot and unity and alot more and it was easier to setup and use than this

Comment: [Did you try the solution described here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/466607/error-c3859-virtual-memory-range-for-pch-exceeded.html)?

Comment: @DMGregory not yet im still reinstalling the UE4 from the epic launcher i don't really need the source code someone said it could be the answer that's why i went for it though it won't be much of a help more painful as a process tbh if i used the source code im trying to make a new game no need for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Windows paging file is virtual memory, stored on the hard drive that Windows can use when it runs out of physical memory to perform operations.  Obviously hard drive speeds are considerably slower than memory so this is never optimal but sometimes essential.

To check the size of your existing paging file, you need to do the following:

1. Right-click on This PC and open Properties.
2. Select Advanced System Properties.
3. Click Advanced tab.
4. Under Performance, click Settings.
5. Under Performance Options, click Advanced tab.

Here you will see information about the paging file and you can click on the Change button to alter this although most of the time, Windows is just set to automatically manage.

If this is the case and you're still getting the error, you may need to check how much physical space the hard drive has left because if it hasn't got room to create a paging file, it won't be able to use it.

As for installation, I've always used the Epic Launcher and never had any problems installing any version of the engine.

Comment: I am trying this now installing the UE4 4.25.1 version again from the epic launcher

there is enough physical disk space maybe the ram needs to be bigger too later

after i install it ill tell u if its fixed